# Any way to reliably navigate to the Apex Jobs page in both Classic and Lightning from a Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, asyncapexjob

In some basic setup UI written in Visualforce, I want a link that takes the user to the "Apex Jobs" page in both Classic and Lightning.

I note that "/707" (the key prefix for `AsyncApexJob`) does not work and that the URLs are different (and AFAIK not guaranteed API) but I guess I could switch between them:

- /apexpages/setup/listAsyncApexJobs.apexp
- /lightning/setup/AsyncApexJobs/home

Any cleaner approach?

Comment: It's still "switching" and might be what you're doing - but using [sf.force.one](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_visualforce/lex_dev_visualforce_navigation) in VF can at least help you make that distinction. I personally haven't found a way of having the "classic" and "lightning" way in terms of URL construction not simply be two different options so I'm interested as well.

Answer (score 0):

As this is basic setup UI I went for:

```
private PageReference addJobsMessages(PageReference pr) {
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, ''
        + 'Open Apex Jobs page in a new tab'
        + ' in <a href="/apexpages/setup/listAsyncApexJobs.apexp" target="_blank">Classic</a>'
        + ' or in <a href="/lightning/setup/AsyncApexJobs/home" target="_blank">Lightning Experience</a>'
    ));
    return pr;
}
```

with:

```
<apex:pageMessages escape="false"/>
```

in the page.